# Getting syntax error in teradata sql query, missing keyword between var and 'NOT'

Tags: jdbc, teradata-sql-assistant, teradatasql

I'm trying out this query but I'm getting a syntax error, I'm not sure what the correct syntax would be so looking for some help here, the query is shown below:

```
select
    rg.col_tar,
    count(distinct rg.col_tar)
from ref_table1 rg
full outer join ref_table_2 ad
ON rg.table_prime=ad.table_prime
where (
    (CONCAT(rg.col1,
        rg.col2,
        rg.col3,
        rg.col4))
        as part_addr_ref NOT= (CONCAT(ad.col1,
        ad.col2,
        ad.col3,
        ad.col4))
        as part_addr_before
)
```

For this query I'm getting the error:

```
Syntax Error: Expected something between the word 'part_addr_ref' and 'NOT' keyword
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks!

I tried to join based on where condition but got syntax error

Comment: Why do you think this is valid syntax in the first place? Did you mean `<>` (the SQL standard symbol for not equals), or possibly `!=` ?

Comment: I also have my doubts about having an `AS` in a `WHERE` clause, but maybe that is some kind of non-standard extension from Teradata.

Comment: I tried `!=`  and `<>` gives me the same syntax error, usually `NOT=` gives me the result, I tried looking for the right keyword but struggling to find that in Teradata documentation.

Comment: I also took a look at the Teradata docs, and I also didn't see a reference, I only saw some references to `NE`, which would be odd in my opinion, but maybe something you could try as well. Otherwise you would need to use NOT (something = something else). Also, it is possible that the parse is confused because of that `as part_addr_ref` and `as part_addr_before`.

Comment: I have my suspicion `as part_addr_ref` and `as part_addr_before` as well, I can try NOT(something=something else) and give you an update!

Comment: Yes, the "AS" clauses are the issue. Teradata actually does support `x NOT = y` as legacy (deprecated) syntax but standard `x<>y` or `NOT x=y` would be preferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct syntax:

```
SELECT * 
FROM PERSONS t01
FULL OUTER JOIN
PERSONS t02
ON
    t01.PERSON_ID = t02.PERSON_ID
WHERE (
         NOT (CONCAT(t01.FIRST_NAME,t01.LAST_NAME) = 
              CONCAT(t02.FIRST_NAME,t02.LAST_NAME)
      );
```